# Create new column by dividing two columns in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query set up in SQL Server:

```
Select [Month]
  ,[Users]
  ,[Shows]
  ,[Clicks]
  ,[Orders]
  ,[Sales_Revenue]
From [dbo].[Perf]
Where Sales_Revenue > 5000000
```

I want from this query to also include a command where I divide `Sales_Rev` by `Orders` and create an `Average Order` column.

Comment: Have you tried adding `,[Sales_Revenue]/[Orders] as Average_Order` to your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `[Sales_Revenue]/[Orders] as Average Order` in your select query.

```
Select [Month]
  ,[Users]
  ,[Shows]
  ,[Clicks]
  ,[Orders]
  ,[Sales_Revenue]
  ,[Sales_Revenue]/[Orders] AS [Average Order]
From [dbo].[Perf]
Where Sales_Revenue > 5000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle 'Divide By Zero' error when your **Orders = 0**, use [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Select [Month]
  ,[Users]
  ,[Shows]
  ,[Clicks]
  ,[Orders]
  ,[Sales_Revenue]
 ,[Sales_Revenue]/NULLIF([Orders],0) AS 'Average Order'
From [dbo].[Perf]
Where Sales_Revenue > 5000000
```